# Spring Boot -- how do I print logs to the console?

Tags: java, spring, logging

I only see Spring Boot related logs, and mine don't appear. I've been using the `Logger` this way:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class); 
logger.debug("saving user...");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the Spring Boot Reference under [Logging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging) already? Otherwise that's a good start.

Comment: by default, log level set to info either change the log level to debug or do logger.info